# best way to manage auth with bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm working on a Flutter application that features a complex UI with a bottom navigation bar, that include five different pages. Among these pages, one doesn't require authentication, while the rest require user authentication to display content:

If the user possesses a token: Display content.
Otherwise: Present a login page, allowing the user to access the create account page as well.

My attempt to manage this functionality using Bloc in Flutter hasn't been successful, specifically with the shared Bloc instance across these pages.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on effectively implementing Bloc architecture to handle authentication across multiple pages within this navigation setup. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your bloc files (or at least their templates).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience i have designed an `authentication Bloc` that manages the user's authentication state. Bloc will emit different states based on whether the user is authenticated or not.

```
// States
abstract class AuthenticationState {}

class AuthenticatedState extends AuthenticationState {
  // User details or tokens
}

class UnauthenticatedState extends AuthenticationState {}

// Events
abstract class AuthenticationEvent {}

class CheckAuthenticationEvent extends AuthenticationEvent {}

class LogoutEvent extends AuthenticationEvent {}

// Bloc
class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  AuthenticationBloc() : super(UnauthenticatedState()) {
    on<CheckAuthenticationEvent>((event, emit) {
      // Check authentication status 
      bool isAuthenticated = /* logic to check authentication */;

      if (isAuthenticated) {
        emit(AuthenticatedState());
      } else {
        emit(UnauthenticatedState());
      }
    });

    on<LogoutEvent>((event, emit) {
      // Logout logic
      emit(UnauthenticatedState());
    });
  }
}
```

Will wrapping the `MaterialApp` with `BlocProvider` to share the single bloc instance throughout the application.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  late final AuthenticationBloc _authenticationBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => _authenticationBloc,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Application',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authenticationBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And will be used among all your four screen requiring authentication like below

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthenticatedState) {
          // Content for authenticated users
          return AuthenticatedContent();
        } else {
          // Login page for unauthenticated users
          // If you wanna navigate to login page than do it from BlocListner.
          return LoginPage();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly, will invoke `CheckAuthenticationEvent` events when user changes page from the navigation bar like this:

```
BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(CheckAuthenticationEvent());
```

Comment: While this works for most smaller applications this approach does not seem scalable when having a lot of different screens in your application. What would be the best approach to manage an auth based navigation globally, ideally directly in main.dart when loading in, therefore listening on a global level and navigating as such when that state changes. 

When doing that, you will hit issues like Navigator is not yet available when wrapping it with a BlocListener for example.. So if you have any ideas that would be awesome.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question so i can help you and come up with an accurate and well composted answer, Like for now i'm thinking you want a global authentication rather than the module wise, like in some my production application we manage authentication like this only. It goes like When app starts it checks that the application possess a precinct token or not and navigate based on that to either home or login page.